# Duplicate or replicate lines based on column value

Tags: unix, command-line, bioinformatics

I'd like to take a 6 column (~1.3 million line) file, and duplicate the lines based on the value in column 4. Input:

```
chr1    6209    6234    2   255 +
chr1    6686    6710    1   255 +
chr1    6755    6780    3   255 +
```

Output:

```
chr1    6209    6234    2   255 +
chr1    6209    6234    2   255 +
chr1    6686    6710    1   255 +
chr1    6755    6780    3   255 +
chr1    6755    6780    3   255 +
chr1    6755    6780    3   255 +
```

I've found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162664/replicate-lines-in-text-file-according-to-a-column-value) which was very similar, but when I attempted to employ the code I was unable to maintain my columns:

Please forgive my scripting ignorance. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{c=$4; while(c-->0) print}' file

chr1 6209 6234 2 255 +
chr1 6209 6234 2 255 +
chr1 6686 6710 1 255 +
chr1 6755 6780 3 255 +
chr1 6755 6780 3 255 +
chr1 6755 6780 3 255 +
```